# copy some fields (structure only) into an existing table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a recent version of MariaDB on a recent version of XAMPP. PHPmyadmin is available.

---

Let's say I carefully created a grand table with a huge number of fields. Let's call this `grand_table`. I chose useful field-names, set up appropriate data types for different types of data.

I want to use `grand_table` as source of ready-made fields for ***adding*** fields to future tables. (E.g., if I need to add an email field to an existing table, I don't want to think about datatypes etc., I just want to copy the email field from `grand_table`. This way I can reduce having to think about it, and also reduce fat-finger typing errors).

Let's say I have another table with a few fields in it. Let's call this `fresh_table`.

I want to copy **only the structure (i.e. the field-names, datatypes etc.)** of 20 fields from `grand_table` to `fresh_table`. I **don't** want to copy any data (there actually isn't any data in `grand_table`).

The 2 tables do not have any common fields among them. So there's no common `id` field (it shouldn't matter anyway I think because I'm not concerned with importing *data* here).

---

I know it's possible to **add** fields to an existing table using:

```
ALTER TABLE `fresh_table` ADD field1 VARCHAR(60), 
field2 VARCHAR(60), field2 VARCHAR(60), 
etc... ;
```

I also know it's possible to create a new table **using fields from an existing table** using:

```
CREATE TABLE animals2 AS 
SELECT animal                -- only the columns you want
FROM animals 
WHERE FALSE;                 -- and no data
```

---

**My question is:** is it possible to combine `ALTER` and `SELECT .. FROM` to ***add*** fields (structure only, no data) to an ***existing table*** from another existing table? And if not, is there some other way to achieve the same objective?

Comment: Once you are satisfied with either of the answers below, it will be valuable to put closure to your question by marking one of them as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alter` + `select ... from` will not work for an existing table. Workaround would be something like this:

```
create table large_table (id int, firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20), age int);
create table fresh_table (field1 int, field2 int);
create table new_table as select id, firstname, field1, field2 from large_table, fresh_table where 1=0;
select * from new_table;
```

That will give you columns from fresh_table and large_table. You can then drop fresh_table and rename new_table to fresh_table.

Comment: This is fantastic -- exactly what i wanted. This way, I can use my `grand_table` as a template to spawn new tables. You've turned me into a table spawning beast.

Answer (score 1):

this is impossible cause the 2 table don't have any condition.If they have, you can just do this:

```
    CREATE TABLE animals2 AS 
      SELECT animal                -- only the columns you want
        FROM animals anm
        join animals1 anm1
        on anm.animal=anm1.animal
      WHERE FALSE;
```